# Visual Studio MSDeploy publish ignore file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, publishing, msdeploy

I'm trying to ignore a file when publishing a web application via Visual Studio 2015 to a IIS Server. I'm publishing with `msdeploy` using `WMSVC`.
Therefore I created a publish profile from a IIS website. The relevant part of the publish profile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>appsettings.json</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The problem is that no matter which path or file I use the file will not be ignored. Here some things I've tried:

- Path `appsettings.json`
- Path `SiloLocal/src/SiloLocal/appsettings.json` with SiloLocal beeing the project name
- Path `**\appsettings.json`
- Emptying the temp folder `AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp` where the website is copied to before beeing published

Did someone experience the same problem? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Build Action on the file by going to the properties of the file in VS and change to None.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunateley that option is not present in VS 2015.

Comment: Yes, it is present in VS2015.  I added a screenshot to the answer above.  Take a look.

Comment: Strange, I dont see the "Advanced" node. Do I have to activate that somehow?

Comment: Try hitting the F4 key or you can go to View|Properties Window.

Comment: I see the properties window, but there is only a node "Misc". When I expand it I see the options "File Name" and "Full Path", but no "Advanced" or "Build Action" in sight.

Comment: You have to select a file then you will see the other options under Properties.  Select the file you want to be ignored.

Comment: I do, but nothing changes. Still only "File Name" and "Full Path".

Comment: You have to select the file from the Solution Explorer window not the Source Control Explorer window.

Comment: I already assumed that, so that's what I've been already doing.

Comment: Are these files included in the project?  Easy way to check is to right click and see if the "Include In Project" is listed.  They must be included in the project to set their Build Action.

Comment: @Guillermo Have you found a solution to this problem? I have tried the exact same steps as you and my appsettings.json is never excluded from deployment.

Comment: @0xced Sorry, I don't remember and I'm not working at that firm anymore so I don't have access, but I think there was some workaround.